# Android alert alignement issue with radio button

Tags: android, android-layout, radio-button

I am very new to `android` programming. I created an `alert box` having a title question and body contains answers `(radio Button)`.

1 . I want to reduce the fort size of title (My Question)
2 . Align radio options below the text center..

[image]

My `Dialogbox.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#800080" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/namelayout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="73dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="5am-6am" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="73dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="6am-8am" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="73dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="6pm-8pm" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="73dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="8pm-11pm" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radiogroub"
        android:layout_width="280dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/namelayout"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal" 
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/sms1"
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/sms2"
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/sms3"
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/sms4"
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp" />
    </RadioGroup>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/btnlayout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/radiogroub"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/sendbtn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:text="Send" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/closebtn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:text="Close" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Your `xml` is totally different from the `screen` you have pasted here.

Comment: Yes...the screen is just a demo....i want to align radio directly under the text....i mean center

Answer (score 0):

Use this layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#800080"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/namelayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_weight="0"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:visibility="visible" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="5am-6am" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="6am-8am" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="6pm-8pm" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="8pm-11pm" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radiogroub"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center" >

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/sms1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center" >

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/sms2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center" >

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/sms3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center" >

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/sms4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </RadioGroup>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/btnlayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_weight="0"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/sendbtn"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Send" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/closebtn"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Close" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```